# change rows to column based on salesperson

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with some product that was sold by some sales person. after selling it different sales person gets royalty for the same product in different % based on their position. All the rows for the same product but different sales person displays in different rows but I want it in same row if the product and transactionID is same. but the sales person name and royalty should show in row like below example. I tried in Dynamic Pivot and dynamic cross tab as well but not able to solve it. may be I was not able to use it properly. could someone please help me on it.

I have tried Dynamic Pivot: (I don't want result like this)

```
TranID  Product qty UntPrice    TotPrice    JOHN    LUCY
10011   Laptop  2   75          150         15  7.5
10012   Camara  3   15          45          4.5 2.25
```

---

```
--drop table #Royalty
Create table #Royalty
(
TranID int,
Product char(10),
Qty int,
UntPrice money,
TotPrice money,
SalesPrsn char(10),
[Royalty%] int,
[royalty$] money
)

insert into #Royalty values (10011,'Laptop', 2, 75,150,'JOHN',10,15)
insert into #Royalty values (10012,'Camara', 3, 15,45,'JOHN',10,4.5)
insert into #Royalty values (10011,'Laptop', 2, 75,150,'LUCY',5,7.5)
insert into #Royalty values (10012,'Camara', 3, 15,45,'LUCY',5,2.25)

select * from #Royalty
```

---

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(c.SalesPrsn) FROM #Royalty c FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') ,1,1,'')
set @query = 'SELECT TranID,Product,Qty, untprice, TotPrice, ' + @cols + ' from 
            (select TranID,Product,Qty, untprice, TotPrice, SalesPrsn, [Royalty$] from #Royalty) x
            pivot 
            (max([Royalty$]) for [SalesPrsn] in (' + @cols + ')) p '
execute(@query)
```

Original data:

```
TranID Product Qty UntPrice TotPrice SalesPrsn  Royalty% Royalty$
10011   Laptop   2  75      150     JOHN        10%      15
10012   Camara   3  15      45      JOHN        10%       4.5
10011   Laptop   2  75      150     LUCY         5%       7.5
10012   Camara   3  15      45      LUCY         5%       2.25
```

Expected Result data:

```
TranID  Product Qty UntPrice TotPrice SalesPrsn Royalty% Royalty$ SalesPrsn Royalty% Royalty$
10011   Laptop   2   75       150      JOHN       10%     15       LUCY       5%      7.5
10012   Camara   3   15        45      JOHN       10%      4.5     LUCY       5%      2.25
```

got using Dynamic Pivot: (I don't want result like this)

```
TranID  Product qty UntPrice    TotPrice    JOHN    LUCY                
10011   Laptop  2   75      150     15  7.5             
10012   Camara  3   15      45      4.5 2.25
```

It would be greatly appreciated if someone help me on it.

Comment: If this query is for report like SSRS report, it will be much easier to do it there

Comment: Thank you for the reply but it is not for SSRS.

Answer (score 0):

The column names must be unique in the result so you can not repeat salesPrsn etc columns for different sales person. The following script will give you the expected results but the columns names are prefixed with the person name. You can them to nay name you want, e.g. SalesPrsn1, SalesPrn2 etc.

```
Create table #Royalty
(
TranID int,
Product char(10),
Qty int,
UntPrice money,
TotPrice money,
SalesPrsn char(10),
[Royalty%] int,
[royalty$] money
)

insert into #Royalty values (10011,'Laptop', 2, 75,150,'JOHN',10,15)
insert into #Royalty values (10012,'Camara', 3, 15,45,'JOHN',10,4.5)
insert into #Royalty values (10011,'Laptop', 2, 75,150,'LUCY',5,7.5)
insert into #Royalty values (10012,'Camara', 3, 15,45,'LUCY',5,2.25)

select * from #Royalty


DECLARE @SalesPerson TABLE (SalesPrsn char(10), Rid int identity not null);

INSERT @SalesPerson(SalesPrsn)
SELECT DISTINCT SalesPrsn FROM #Royalty;

-- SELECT * FROM @SalesPerson;
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(max);
DECLARE @RID int;
DECLARE @Prsn char(10);
SET @SQL=N'
SELECT TranID, MAX(Product) AS Product, MAX(Qty) AS Qty, MAX(UntPrice) AS UntPrice, MAX(TotPrice) AS TotPrice'

SELECT @RId=MIN(RID) FROM @SalesPerson;
WHILE @RID IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    SELECT @Prsn=SalesPrsn FROM @SalesPerson WHERE Rid=@RID;
    SET @SQL=@SQL+N',
        MAX(CASE WHEN SalesPrsn='''+@Prsn+''' THEN SalesPrsn ELSE NULL END) AS ['+RTRIM(@Prsn)+'_SalesPrsn],
        MAX(CASE WHEN SalesPrsn='''+@Prsn+''' THEN [Royalty%] ELSE NULL END) AS ['+RTRIM(@Prsn)+'_Royalty%],
        MAX(CASE WHEN SalesPrsn='''+@Prsn+''' THEN [Royalty$] ELSE NULL END) AS ['+RTRIM(@Prsn)+'_Royalty$]'
    SELECT @RId=MIN(RID) FROM @SalesPerson WHERE Rid>@RID;
END
SET @SQL=@SQL+'
FROM #Royalty
GROUP BY TranID;'
EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;
```

Comment: Thank you Peter, Let me try with this code. Really appreciate your help